# Eigen loadMarket does not compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, eigen

In Windows, MSVS2017

```
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/SparseExtra>

// other code

SparseMatrix<double> A; // with `MatrixXd A;` it displays the same error
VectorXd b;

loadMarket(A, "A.txt");
loadMarket(b, "b.txt");
```

does not compile with error:

Error   C2039   'reserve': is not a member of 'Eigen::Matrix'   scanning-test   C:\Users\wurmd\Work\scanning2\build_deps\eigen-src\unsupported\Eigen\src\SparseExtra\MarketIO.h    170

**Note:**

```
SparseMatrix<double> A;
VectorXd b;
// some processing
saveMarket(A, "A.txt");
saveMarket(b, "b.txt");
```

Compiles, runs, and saves the matrix and vector in human readable form.

Does anyone know a workaround? (currently waiting for an account at https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/ to report this bug)

Comment: You must not include any files from the `src` subdirectories. Just `#include <unsupported/Eigen/SparseExtra>`. I think there is a duplicate for this, but can't find it now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import matrix market files with eigen library in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57625758/how-to-import-matrix-market-files-with-eigen-library-in-c)

Comment: @chtz , made the change, did not fix it. Still does not compile with same error

Comment: Provide a [mre], then.

Comment: This compiles fine: https://godbolt.org/z/wVB2tv

Comment: It does? Dang it. That suggests OS-related issue: I'm in windows, MSVS2017.

Comment: Works fine with MSVC as well: https://godbolt.org/z/SNYt7F The code you posted so far obviously won't compile.

Comment: This is really disheartening :(. Made a separate minimal MSVS project and it compiles with the above. The next step in complexity is wrapping the above in a gtest TEST, but the minimal project won't link `Error LNK2038 mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in main.obj minimal_exe C:\Users\wurmd\Work\minimal\build\gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) 1`. I'll have to give up for now :(
Thanks for the help @chtz

Comment: Hm, it occurs to me that I got distracted. I don't need gtest, I can proceed without it, and have discovered what is causing the compilation failure

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to use `saveMarket` or `loadMarket` with Vectors. You should use `saveMarketVector` and `loadMarketVector`

```
SparseMatrix<double> A;
VectorXd b;
// some processing
saveMarket(A, "A.txt");
saveMarketVector(b, "b.txt");

...

SparseMatrix<double> Ain; 
VectorXd bin;

loadMarket(Ain, "A.txt");
loadMarketVector(bin, "b.txt");
```

does the job